# Dynamic column cell width

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports

I have some Jasper reports which are displayed in HTML format. I would like the width of the columns in the HTML tables to automatically resize to fit the content of the widest cell (in that column), such that all the data is displayed.

Currently this does not happen because the HTML generated by Jasper specifies fixed widths for the <table> and some <td> elements, e.g.

```
<td style="width: 20px; height: 17px;">
  <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px;">foo-bar-baz@examp</span>
</td>
```

I can't simply remove all these width properties (using JavaScript), because (as shown in the HTML above) any data that would be hidden when using these widths is not even returned to the client-side

Cheers,
Don

Comment: Have you tried using [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?group_id=83). Its an IDE for writing JasperReports. It could make your life simpler.

Comment: I have the same issue.  If you want columns spread evenly across the avaiable width, its not possible.  In Jasper Stuido, when you create a table with say 10 columns, it sqashes the columns into a tiny area with a width of just 22px.  You have to then edite every cell and manually change the width to some value you calculate- it takes hours.  Then when you want to change it.. for this reason I NEVER use tables any more. I use subreportsfor just about everything, as you can change their width by dragging.

Answer (score 7):

While not perfect, you could flag the field to stretch with overflow. This would at least give you all the data. In your jrxml file it would be similar to:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" hyperlinkType="None">
    <reportElement style="Report Sub-Title" x="0" y="84" width="802" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA["For the period ...]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I'm afraid I don't know of any feature of Jasper reports that would allow the dynamic resizing of column widths - It is probably one of those things that makes sense for HTML but little sense for other output formats such as PDF.

Comment: Agree with Jamie Love. But I would apply his suggestion on the columnHeader tag, for the property to apply for the whole column.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!  I found that when the column stretches to fit the contents there is no padding next to the adjacent column.  Adding `<box padding="10"/>` within the `textField` element fixed that issue as suggested by [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14284593/848668)

Answer (score 5):

The developers made a conscious decision to not allow cell width to stretch. For columns to change their width based on the content, it must be done through programming. A helpful tool: [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/).

> DynamicJasper creates reports
> dynamically, defining at runtime the
> columns, column width (auto width),
> groups, variables, fonts, charts,
> crosstabs, sub reports (that can also
> be dynamic), page size and everything
> else that you can define at design
> time.

The [JasperReports forum](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522554/how-dynamically-increaze-column-width) and [DynamicJasper HOW-TO](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-create-bar-code-columns/) both have examples of automatic (dynamic) column widths.

```java
FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
drb.addColumn("State", "state", String.class.getName(),20)
        .addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(),30)
        .addColumn("Quantity", "quantity", Long.class.getName(),60,true)
        .addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(),70,true)
        .addBarcodeColumn("Bar-Code", "amount", Long.class.getName(), BarcodeTypes.USD3, true,
false,null, 100, true, ImageScaleMode.FILL, null)
        .addGroups(1)
        .setDetailHeight(30)
        .setTitle("November 2006 sales report")
        .setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
        .setUseFullPageWidth(true);     

DynamicReport dr = drb.build();
```

Passing in `true` when calling `addColumn` indicates to use a *fixed* width. Leaving the parameter off or passing `false` will set the column width dynamically. You may also have to call `setUseFullPageWidth( true )` for the auto widths to activate, but I'm not sure on this point.

Answer (score -3):

In iReport there is an option called "Stretch Type". Select "Relative to Band Height"

Comment: @Carlos: That will cause the cell to stretch in height, not width.