# Can JasperReports produce Excel file with column widths auto adjusted to contents?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

When `JasperReports` outputs a file in the `Excel` xls format, the columns when viewed are only the fixed width determined in the jasper XML.

This is a problem when the data in the columns is of varying widths, causing some columns to wrap.

I've had a look at the [API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) and the [DTD](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd) and there doesn't seem to be a way of setting the column widths to auto adjust.

i.e.instead of displaying as

```
  emailAdress
  @email.com
```

display as

```
  emailAdress@email.com
```

Is it possible to do this at all?

This question is similar to [Jasper report column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300383/jasper-report-column-width)

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve the effect of auto column's width with help of ***[net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column)*** property. If we set the value as ***true*** the *auto width* will be enabled. The default value of this property is ***false***.

### The working sample

We can use the *csv* datasource and simple report designed in *Jaspersoft Studio* to check the result.

The report's design will be simple - only one *textField* in *Detail* band.

#### Datasource

It is very simple - only one column *email*. The first row contains just a column's name. We can told the datasource adapter to skip this first line.

```
email
emailAdress@email.com
short@have.org
a@b.net
```

#### Report's template

The width of *textField* will be too small to show the full text.

To *"turn on"* the auto width we should set the *net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column* property.

The *jrxml* will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_auto_width_excel" pageWidth="100" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="100" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="c899fa54-7405-4371-b34f-429f5959b593">
    <queryString language="csv">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="04d0735d-a1b6-4a8f-b252-b8772d7c5abd">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The generated *xls* file without using property looks like this (opened in *MS Excel*):

[image]

The generated *xls* file with *net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column* property looks like this (opened in *MS Excel*):

[image]

---

*Notes*

- In both cases the *xls* files were generated in *Jaspersoft Studio*.
- The [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures) article contains more information about tricks of exporting report to *MS Excel* format