# Text wrapping issue in generated pdf file

Tags: jasper-reports, overlapping, word-wrap, export-to-pdf

I have an issue related to wrapping of text in pdf format. For all the formats like xls,rtf, and pptx the report works fine,however in pdf some text gets wrapped i.e. some letters of the text especially the last few letters gets printed in the next line. I have tried almost all the options in the properties for that text. The only way I could reduce the effect was by changing the pdf font name to times roman for those text. However even this does not work in some case.

The snippet contains problem `TextField`:

```
<textField  isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="560" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
    <box leftPadding="2">
        <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
        <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS"  isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CustState}]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I would be very grateful if you share some solution for this.
Thanks...

P.s I get this issue when i generate the report from Ireport 4.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use Font Extensions. Your issue is very likely because JasperReports (iText) isn't using the font that you want it to be using when generating the PDF. Font Extensions solve this.

Second, it's possible that you're encountering an issue that got fixed. The JasperReports 4.1.1 Change Log includes this:

`the net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy configuration property is now deprecated as the PDF text rendering code was refactored so that text is rendered exactly like in AWT`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I would not be able to use the second option as Ireport 4.0.2 jars are already deployed in the server for the application. But yes the wrapping issue does gets solved when I use the other versions of Ireport im my standalone machine.I have not tried with 4.1.1 . I tried using 4.0.1 and it was working fine. However I need to find a way in Ireport 4.0.2 version to correct this issue. couple of questions...(1)If the issue is related to font then why is the problem not showing up for some text with the same font type and same other properties?

Comment: 2)using font extensions ,my understanding is we can add the font in the tool,but it will not be added in the server.. right?since we are deploying .jasper files in the server ,do we need to add the jar created using font extension in the server as well?

Comment: Yes: Font Extensions exist specifically to make it possible to deploy the same font on the server. It will be an additional .jar file on the server.

Comment: @mdahlman I have got the same issue and I have posted that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533330/text-alignment-issue-with-report-generated-as-pdf-file-when-using-markup-html). How can I use font extensions?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this by adding a space end of the text.I am also using jasper4.0.2 and It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Some elements (TextField or StaticText) can increase its height depends on `stretch type` and `stretch with overflow` properties. But element's width can not be changed without programming.

The quote from `iReport Ultimate Guide`:

> **Stretch type** - This attribute defines how to calculate the element
>  height during the print elaboration; the three possible values are as
>  follows:
>
> **NoStretch** - This is the pre-defined stretch type, and it
>  dictates that the element height should be kept equal.
>
> **RelativeToBandHeight** - The element height is increased proportionally to the increasing size of the band; this is useful for vertical lines that simulate table borders.
>
> **RelativeToTallestObject** - The element modifies its height according to the deformation of the nearest element: this option is also used with the element group, which is an element group mechanism not managed by iReport
>
>
> **Stretch with overflow** - When it is selected, this option allows the textfield to adapt vertically to the content, if the element is not sufficient to contain all the text line

You can use, for example [ColumnBuilder](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/ar/com/fdvs/dj/domain/builders/ColumnBuilder.html) class from [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/) API to set column width.

You can also read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300383/dynamic-column-cell-width).

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks a lot for the reply..However I think I was not able to explain my problem clearly to you. Let me try to rephrase and explain to u with the problem that I am encountering in my report. I have a textfield whose values get populated dynamically in a table from the xml datasource that I have used.The width is sufficent for a two letter word to fit. However when I generate the report some text gets wrapped,even though some text in the same field is working fine.

Comment: Do you have different behavior for text with the same length?

Comment: Yes...As I stated earlier for the same textfield(with same length) ,the texts behaves differently

Comment: Can you post the snippet of report?

Comment: Hi Alex,Here is the snippet of the report where I encounter the problem..
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="560" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
    <box leftPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS"  isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CustState}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Comment: What minimum length causes problem?

Comment: I've just checked your textfield: the long text was cut, I did not see text with two or more lines per element

Comment: yes alex..that is exactly the problem I am encountering.It works perfectly fine in some case and in other it creates the problem. I could have shared with the screenshot of the pdf text where I have the problem,but Im not allowed to post images right now..have you come across such problem before?

Comment: Do you want that the textfield's height will be increased if the text is too long for field?

Comment: Try this: <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="660" y="0" width="60" height="21"/>
    <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>

Answer (score 0):

**For text wrapping issue in pdf export in iReport 4.0.2**:

Convert your fonts as Jar, then add as external jar, definitely it will work.

In iReport designer:

**Step 1)** Tool -> Option -> Fonts -> Install your fonts

**Step 2)** Select that font -> click on export as extension [ make it as JAR ]

**Step 3)** Go to Classpath -> click on ADD Jar -> add your font jar -> OK

Now preview the report.