# Text alignment issue with report generated as PDF file when using markup="html" using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, ireport

I have the following data to be printed in the PDF,

```
101 HARRIER WAY<br>OMVILLE<br>BELLSHIRE<br>OM1  1HA<br>
```

It needs to be displayed in the following way,

```
101 HARRIER WAY
OMVILLE
BELLSHIRE
OM1  1HA
```

But is is printing like the following,

[image]

**UPDATE:**

When I use other text in the place of `OMVILLE` say

```
101 HARRIER WAY<br>HELLO WORLD BANGALORE<br>BELLSHIRE<br>OM1  1HA<br>
```

it works well. I don't have any idea why it is not working when I give `OMVILLE`

[image]

**Code:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="accountStatement" pageWidth="720" pageHeight="1008" columnWidth="680" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isTitleNewPage="true">
    <parameter name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="914" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="117" y="141" width="297" height="105" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font size="9" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" tabStopWidth="60"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

I am running this code using *iReport 4.0.2* and my *JasperReports* version is 4.

For running the above code use all the input parameters as default values and for address parameter give below one as input.

```
101 HARRIER WAY<br>OMVILLE<br>BELLSHIRE<br>OM1  1HA<br>
```

**P.S:** I am generating the jrxml in PDF format.

Comment: Is it browser specific?

Comment: I did not get u .. browser specific mean .. ? I run this on IE7/IE8.

Comment: have you tried running it on Chrome or firefox?

Comment: Yaa I am currently running on firefox .. but still the error comes here.

Comment: @Che I've just test your sample - it is works perfect. What version of *JasperReports\iReport* are you using?

Comment: @Che Can you post the source code of generated *html* file?

Comment: @AlexK Sorry for the late response. I have added the code pls let me know the issue. I use ireport to generate the PDF format of this jrxml.

Comment: @improver I have updated the question with code. Can u pls try to help me with this one ..

Comment: @Che Yes. The strange bug - I've got it in *iReport 4.0.2*, but it works fine in *5.1.0*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample works fine with this versions of *JasperReports API*: **4.0.1** and **4.1.1**, but I've faced the same problem as you with **4.0.2** version.

#### What is difference?

We can compare two versions of implementation of *JRPdfExporter*, for example the *4.1.1* and *4.0.2* versions.

As you can see the source code of [*PdfTextRenderer*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/PdfTextRenderer.html) is different for this two versions, for example the method [*draw*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/PdfTextRenderer.html#draw%28%29) is changed. This method *draw()* contains the calling of [ColumnText.go()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.html#go%28%29) method of *iText* framework. This method is using for drawing text in *pdf* document.

#### Possible solutions:

1. You can upgrade your vestion of *JasperReports* library. The last one is *5.2.0* and your sample works with it. Your sample works well even with *4.1.1* as I mentioned before
2. You can fix the source code of *PdfTextRenderer* class if you can not upgrade the version of *JR* library.

---

#### About testing your issue

I've wrote a small sample for testing your issue. I've used the *Maven* project - for simple switching between *JR* libraries versions.

The source code of *Java* class for testing issue:

```java
public static void testReport() throws JRException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("address", "101 HARRIER WAT<br/>OMVILLE<br/>BELLSHIRE<br/>OM1 1HA<br/>");

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
}
```

And the "slim" test *jrxml* file was:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="accountStatement" pageWidth="720" pageHeight="1008" columnWidth="680" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isTitleNewPage="true">
    <parameter name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="914" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="117" y="141" width="297" height="105"/>
                <textElement markup="html">
                    <font size="9" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Okay let me try this one .. :)

Comment: Alex as I have many other reports along with this report in the project so I cannot upgrade or downgrade the version. As of 2nd option how can I change the source code .. is their any other solution which I can do in the jrxml file like using rich font or style or some other way .. my data comes as input `101 HARRIER WAY<br>OMVILLE<br>BELLSHIRE<br>OM1  1HA<br>` such that I have split-ed this one using delimiter as <br> and used 4 text fields. But still I am facing the problem. Can u suggest me some thing that I can fix right away?

Comment: I am also reading this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964833/text-wrapping-issue-in-pdf-export-in-ireport-4-0-2). How can I use font extensions.

Comment: Did you read [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions) topic? With help of *iReport* you can generate *jar* with your font (*ttf*).

Comment: Mission accomplished .. Thanks a lot. More than this answer your other answers in SO helped me a lot .. :)

Comment: As I thought to use font-extensions like some posts suggested but their is a debate on that in the team saying use default font only `Sanserif`. So I used trail and error method on the textfield but still failed.

Comment: Finally removed `html` markup for the text field. Made 4 different text fields for each line saying addres_1, address_2 ... and passing  4 parameters instead of sending as a single address parameter. It worked.

Comment: Even then I got alignment issues. But appending a space at the end of each each textfield has worked like a champ. If I give like this `p{address_1}` it did not aligned properly but when I gave `p{address_1} + " "` it is aligned properly for all 4 parameters. Don't know why but worked. Thought to tell you this .. :)

Comment: Sry to disturb you. The pdf's are opening properly in Windows but when the testing team runs them on unix servers fonts are breaking .. can u tell me any possible solution ?

Comment: Did you use *embedding* font?

Comment: No .. I have used the default fonts .. Helvetica and Sanserif. Any ideas .. ?