# The text in rendering wrong in case using Helvetica font

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, ireport, truetype

I'm using *iReport 5.1.0* to create a few reports inside my application.

My trouble is when I try to put a static text component inside my report and set *Helvetica* font for it, the result is the following:

[image]

This is my jrxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c83e3c14-669c-4175-b99d-6284dea45ccd">
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="be024b7a-7371-42ae-82ad-0d621f56d954" x="0" y="0" width="223" height="65"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Helvetica"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[This is a simple text, This is a simple text, This is a simple text]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

If I change the font everything works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: post your jrxml code.

Comment: @Marco Your issue looks like this case [Text alignment issue with report generated as PDF file when using markup=“html” using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18533330/876298). It seems to me that this is a bug of the engine

Comment: Are you sure? Because my trouble begins on IReport

Comment: I think in case using *Java* code the result will be the same (you can check it). I think the engine (or the 3rd part library used by *JR*) does not "like" this font - may be this font is not decorated well

Comment: Yes, also using the Java code the result is the same. I should solve the problem  changing the JR Version.I try and keep you updated Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue on *iReport 5.2.0*

Comment: @Marco In case using *bold* text everything is fine

Comment: With IReport 5.5.0 everything works

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set lineSpacing for the content.
The line spacing property can increase the space between lines.

for example: lineSpacing="Double"

```
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="596a7b0e-293a-4285-bd17-f7d8563d5f02" x="78" y="0" width="383" height="83"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Helvetica" size="12"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Double"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Static text Static text Static text Static text Static text]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
```