# Text alignment Issues

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports*. When I am trying to create a report I am facing alignment issues like when I entered name field as "BBB" in report it's coming in 2 lines like 2 "BB" in first line and 1 "B" is in second line. But some of the alphabets like AAA,EEE I am getting aligned result.

Comment: You should post the sample (*jrxml* file)

Comment: Refer [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533330/text-alignment-issue-with-report-generated-as-pdf-file-when-using-markup-html for your question. It may be helpful to you