# jasper report 3.1.4 pdf export missing last rows in a 2 column report

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a report with static text that is on 2 columns and 2 pages with styled text(a few words must be bold, italic, underlined) that has to be exported to PDF in Arial font.

The problem: the last one/two rows of the columns disappear (although there would be space for them to print). I cannot post the info of the text because it's a legal, official document.

What I have tried:
1. setting the Arial font to the font map of the exporter:

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, _stream);
FontKey keyArial = new FontKey("Arial", false, false);  
PdfFont fontArial = new PdfFont("Helvetica","Cp1252",false); 

FontKey keyArialBold = new FontKey("Arial", true, false);  
PdfFont fontArialBold = new PdfFont("Helvetica-Bold","Cp1252",false);

Map fontMap = new HashMap();
fontMap.put(keyArial,fontArial);
fontMap.put(keyArialBold,fontArialBold);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.FONT_MAP,fontMap);
```

, this made the styled text show correctly(with bold, italic and underlined).

2. setting net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy to true: [Text wrapping issue in generated pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964833/text-wrapping-issue-in-pdf-export-in-ireport-4-0-2)

, but this did nothing...

3. just in case the first try( nr 1.) was still a problem (because pdf preview still didn't show the styled text correctly) I installed Arial font from windows to iReport, exported it and added it to the classpath of iReport and in the WEB-INF\lib folder of the project (I followed this tutorial: http://javaskeleton.blogspot.fr/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html).

, no visible effects

4. Set top and bottom margins to 0px

, no effect

5. Save the generated report from the browser, then open it with Acrobat Reader XI

, the rows are still missing

Here are the specs for the report:

I'm using iReport 3.6.1 with compatibility for 3.1.4.

The report is for a project that uses java 1.4

Page format: A4 portrait, (sizes are in pixels) top 10, bottom 10, left 20, right 20, columns 2, col width 275, space 5

I have two overlapped centered titles (text fields) that span over the 2 columns, with Print When Expression over a parameter.

I have two groups, one for each page only with a header band. Each header band has two overlapped text fields that have the same Print When Expression over the same parameter. The second band starts with a column break. The fields stretch to the middle of the band, have Stretch Type = Relative to Band Height, Print When Detail Overflows = true, Stretch With Overflow = true. The text in the fields cover both pages almost to the capacity - they fill both columns on both pages (with carriage returns at the end of second page and last row with page x/x). I used "\n" to add carriage return and `<style isBold=\"true\" isUnderline=\"true\" isItalic=\"true\"></style>` for the styled text (of course with Markup = styled setting on the fields).

The report is exported in IE v 11.0.9600.17914. The Acrobat Reader installed on my machine is version XI.

Comment: Update: It seems that the bold text is "pushing" the text downwards and the report calculated the height as if it was normal (unformatted) text to place the automated column break (so with bold text it doesn't know where to place the column break and the text goes beyond the limit into the unknown).

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some issues related to a line of a text field, when it is displayed at the end of a page.
Try changing font size, if allowed.

Similar issues:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/2874-0
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844276/text-field-missing-last-line-mingliu-and-font-size-less-10

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug, I had a similar problem.
Try adding a line break ( "\\n" or whatever works for you ) after the **last** line of  your static text. This helped in my case.

Comment: That's what I eventually did, but it is a bit of an ugly solution. If anybody changes the static text in the future, and don't know about this bug, they will wonder where their text has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem, using Jasper Version 6.1.1, in a two column report. Initially I solved the problem simply inserting a `<br/>` at the end of my text, which was html formated. It worked for the second column, but not for the first (*which I took longer to realize it had a missing line too!*).

I tried creating font extensions and it didn't fix it.
Then I noticed I was using "*proportional*" line spacing, with 0.7 size:

```
<textElement textAlignment="Center" markup="none">
  <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
  <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional" lineSpacingSize="0.7"/>
</textElement>
```

Deleting that `<paragraph>` element fixed the problem and my report is now showing all lines in both columns.

**Important to notice**: I couldn't shrink my text as business needed. I *strongly believe* this is a bug in Jasper's PDF generator.