# How to stretch textfield in a JasperReport as per dynamic content?

Tags: jasper-reports

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="tree-template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="481" leftMargin="57" rightMargin="57" topMargin="72" bottomMargin="72">
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#000000" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="JasperCustomSubReportLocation" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
    <parameter name="JasperCustomSubReportDatasource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="notes" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="state" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="project" class="com.pearson.ltg.qmo.dashboard.domain.QDashProject">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[project]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="theme" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="goals" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="statusDetails" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="mitigation" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="releaseDate" class="java.util.Calendar"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/15)]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="Group2">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/5)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="10"/>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="58" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="4" y="0" width="477" height="56"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="48" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Release Details]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="189" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="7" width="481" height="13" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#9DB1B8"/>
            </frame>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="279" y="7" width="202" height="13"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="79" y="7" width="100" height="13"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{project}.getName()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="7" width="79" height="13"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Platform : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="179" y="7" width="100" height="13"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Release Name :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="47" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Status : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="79" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="79" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Release Date: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="181" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Release Goals]]></text>
            </staticText>
##want this field to auto stretch as per content##
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="80" width="463" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{goals}==null ? "Not Defined":$F{goals}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
##want this field to auto stretch as per content##
            <staticText>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="100" width="98" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Status Details]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="2" y="120" width="463" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{statusDetails}==null ? "Not Defined":$F{statusDetails}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="140" width="98" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Risk Mitigation]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="18" y="160" width="463" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{mitigation}==null?"Not Defined":$F{mitigation}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="79" y="40" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy").format($F{releaseDate}.getTime())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="481" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="12" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="477" height="13" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#9DB1B8"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="0" width="197" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="450" y="0" width="27" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="370" y="0" width="80" height="13" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: How is your report defined, vertical or horizonal?

Comment: Glad you told us what error condition happened. Now, what jasperreports version are you using? How are you editing it?

Comment: I am using iReport to edit it. Jasper Report is of version 3.7.6

Comment: The height of the textfield in the RTF report is not getting adjusted as per the content.

Comment: You should not be setting this: stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject". But I don't think this would be the cause of the problem. (Setting this is correct and sufficient: isStretchWithOverflow="true".)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add the `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` to the textField that you want as an element.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement x="279" y="7" width="202" height="13"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Please note that as of JasperReports Library version 6.10, the `isStretchWithOverflow="true"` property was substituted by `textAdjust="StretchHeight"`. To have newer versions of Jaspersoft Studio use the old property, you can change the JasperReports library version in the compatibility settings ("Window->Preferences->Jaspersoft Studio->Compatibility").

Answer (score 10):

1. Click on the particular textfield in iReport.
2. On the right side, see TextField properties.
3. Check the option "STRETCH WITH OVERFLOW".

It worked in my case.

Comment: This answer resolves my problem, simple and efective.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Jaspersoft Studio**, click on the text field you want to change, navigate to its properties, enter the *Text Field* tab and change Text Adjust to `StretchHeight` (default is `CutText`). Also, if your text field is in the frame, you should set its *Position Type* to `Float`

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution. Modified all the static text fields and all the elements properties to `positionType="Float"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attribute isStretchWithOverflow set is true
`<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">`

Comment: This is exactly the same as an already existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377392/how-to-stretch-textfield-in-a-jasperreport-as-per-dynamic-content/41272512#41272512. There's no need to repeat an existing answer unless you add new information :)

Comment: Note: The existing answer linked by MBorg back in 2020 suggests deprecated usage.  At least with version 6.20.1 ... I see this message when compiling a *.jrxml: 
WARNING: The 'isStretchWithOverflow' attribute is deprecated.  Use the 'textAdjust' attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `textAdjust="StretchHeight"` with `positionType="Float"` solves the growth problem inside a field, but in a list-like layout (but you don't want to make a list) the neighboring fields stay in place.

[image]

I found a solution with frames by trial and error.

Create a frame with `<frame><reportElement positionType="Float" .../> ... </frame>` around the 2 fields and the static text. You can also use the drag and drop functition in Jaspersoft Studio.

It will look something like this:
[image]

Result:[image]

Answer (score 0):

The field can auto stretch with overflow, but it goes down (kinda word wrap) instead of increasing width. In PDF documents that option you look out for, would be of little or no use.

Check this other thread for further info [Dynamic column cell width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300383/dynamic-column-cell-width)

**EDIT** Also check and include jasperreports fonts extension. Maybe it could help on a flawless deploy without OS fonts' issues.

Comment: I am generating a RTF JasperReport, The textfield's height is not auto stretched.

Comment: Got the solution. Modified all the static text fields and all the elements properties to positionType="Float".

Comment: Good. Create the answer and check it so others will know!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JasperSoft Studio then you need to set three properties:

first you need to select the field then set these properties.

1. PositionType(on right side inside appearance property) = float.
2. Stretch Type(on right side inside appearance property) = Releative to
   tallest object.
3. Text Adjust(on right side inside appearance property) = StretchHeight

**Also remember to set band width to stretch.**

Answer (score -1):

[Applicable only to Jasper Table] select the Text Field present inside a column and select
1. Position Type: Fix relative to Top
2. Stretch Type: Relative to Band Height
3. Stretch with Overflow: true
Apply the same to all other columns
Now, when one of the columns grow vertically, then other fields will be aligned center automatically!!
[Result below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onNqh.png)