# Issue with textField position and isStretchWithOverflow baseline shifting

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a JasperReport with a *textField* element.

Simple XML:

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
  <reportElement uuid="2e3604dd-1f53-44d6-ab66-b3e41732955b" x="247" y="229" width="232" height="20"/>
  <textElement>
    <font fontName="CBSwiss721BT-Light"/>
  </textElement>
  <textFieldExpression>
    <![CDATA[$F{meetingPurpose}]]>
  </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

If the length of field's ***meetingPurpose*** value is less than the width of the *textField*, it prints beautifully, however if the length causes the text to wrap and stretch the *textField*, the text is baseline shifted down 1/2 X height.

I don't see anything like cell padding that I can access and I cannot figure this out. If it is a feature, is there an off switch?

Comment: do you have a default style defined in the JRXML or linked style reference?

Answer (score 1):

I may be reading your problem all wrong but, to access Padding right click on the element pick padding and borders

it will alter your xml to look like this

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SYSDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```